# How do you add Font Awesome to Aurelia using aurelia cli version 1.0.0-beta.13 with the webpack option and npm

Tags: aurelia

With version 1.0.0-beta.13 of the aurelia cli with the webpack option selected I am trying to add Font Awesome via npm.  There are several questions regarding this but nothing with the current cli and webpack.  I have installed **Font Awesome** via npm and imported it into my **main.js**

```
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css
```

I have also tried requiring it in my app.html but it still does not work.  I can add the Font Awesome cdn link to my index.ejs and it works as expected but I would like to use it via npm.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try pre-pending font-awesome to your bundle, following the built-in bundler guide?

Comment: Did you have a look at https://aurelia.io/docs/cli/cli-bundler/cook-book#font-awesome-v4

Comment: You are referring to the built in bundler not the current cli with the webpack option selected.  Thanks

Comment: if webpack is the case, then it should just really work. When something doesn't work, it would be a lot faster to help if you could show the error